# Can't read in a file and then write results to a file with scrapy (python)

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm doing some webscraping with scrapy, and I've run into a problem. I've figured out that I can save my scrapy results to a csv file using the following command line:

```
    scrapy crawl spider --set FEED_URI=output.csv --set FEED_FORMAT=csv
```

I also know that I can read in a start url to scrape from a text file by using the following command line input:

```
    scrapy crawl dmoz -a filename=text.txt
```

And my code in my spider is:

```
class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "dmoz"
allowed_domains = ["ebay.com"]

def __init__(self, filename=None):
    if filename:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            self.start_urls = f.readlines()
            print self.start_urls
```

My issue arises when I try to do both of these at once. I want my spider to scrape the url specified in the text file, and then write the output to a csv file. The following command line does not work for some reason, the url is read in (I know for a fact), but the csv file is not written:

```
   scrapy crawl dmoz -a filename=text.txt --set FEED_URI=output.csv --set FEED_FORMAT=csv
```

If anyone sees what I'm doing wrong or has a workaround, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have dynamic start requests, you should use `start_requests()` to yield them, instead of changing `start_urls`.
This is how you should do it:

```
class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
name = "dmoz"
allowed_domains = ["ebay.com"]

def start_requests(self):
    if self.filename:
        with open(self.filename, 'r') as f:
            for url in f.readlines():
                yield scrapy.Request(url)
```

To write the output to a `csv` file, you only need to define the file using the `-o` argument (if you use a valid extension, the feed format will be auto selected):

```
scrapy crawl dmoz -a filename=text.txt -o output.csv
```